# How can i fix a OpenCV QrCode issue?

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling, crash, qr-code

Im reading Qrs from a web cam on Python, i use the detectAndDecodeCurved function to read the Qrs in any angle more quickly.

MRE:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)
camera = True
while camera == True:
    success, image = cap.read()
    qrDetector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()

    data, bbox, rectifiedImage = qrDetector.detectAndDecodeCurved(image) 
    if len(data) > 0:
        print(data)

    cv2.imshow('a', image)
    cv2.waitKey(q)
```

But sometimes the code starts popping three errors about the detectAndDecodeCurved function until the program crashes and i dont find a solution.

#1:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\qrcode.cpp:2487: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator > __cdecl cv::QRCodeDetector::decode(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &)'

> Invalid QR code source points (expected: 'contourArea(src_points) > 0.0'), where
> 'contourArea(src_points)' is 0
> must be greater than
> '0.0' is 0

#2:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\floodfill.cpp:509: error: (-211:One of the arguments' values is out of range) Seed point is outside of image in function 'cv::floodFill'

#3:

data, bbox, rectifiedImage = qrDetector.detectAndDecodeCurved(image)
cv2.error: Unknown C++ exception from OpenCV code

Thank you for reading.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with it, throw the thing in a `try/except` and just re-try.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\samue\Documents\Programacion\proyectoAsistech\controllers\windows.py", line 146, in viewCam
    data, bbox, rectifiedImage = qrDetector.detectAndDecodeCurved(image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\floodfill.cpp:509: error: (-211:One of the arguments' values is out of range) Seed point is outside of image in function 'cv::floodFill'

Comment: The error appears in terminal, but the program continue normally and then suddenly crashes with no advice.

Comment: One of the problems seems to be that the `detectAndDecodeCurved` function is trying to `flood-fill` at a point outside the image. Now, why is this happening - we don't know because you did not provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with your input image. Maybe the issue arises when you try to process an image without an actual code.

Comment: since you're editing this question right now, be sure to add _the image you have problems with_. **do not** require people to get out their webcam and hold a QR code up to their own webcam.